# Vacuums and free space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, vacuum

Do physicists use the terms "vacuum," "quantum vacuum," and "free space" synonymously? For example, I have read that based on conservation arguments, the spontaneous splitting of a photon into an electron-positron pair "in free space" is prohibited. And yet I have also seen this event termed "vacuum polarization," which would seem an odd usage if vacuum and free space are indeed synonymous. (My apologies if any of my premises are invalid; I am just a mathematician.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vacuum is free space, but vacuum polarization is not connected to the diagram describing only the splitting of a photon into an electron-positron, but to the diagram that contains the electron-positron pair in a loop, with a photon in- and outgoing.

Such particles in a Feynman diagram, which cannot be actually detected, are called virtual particles, and the property differentiating them from real particles is that they are off-shell, i.e they do not obey the classical equations of motion and can possess masses which are not allowed by the dispersion relation (the shell imagined here is the hypersurface swept out in energy-momentum space by the energies allowed by the dispersion relation, all real, detectable particles are on-shell). Since the electron-positron pair of the vacuum polarization is off-shell, the energy-momentum conversation arguments prohibiting its production fail since the pair does not obey the classical dispersion relations between energy and momentum.

Comment: Your first paragraph answers my question directly. Your second is also enormously helpful, but may I ask for a more expansive reference?

Comment: I think you should find what you are looking for in any standard QFT book, Peskin/Schröder, Itzykin/Zuber or the like - everything that introduces Feynman diagrams on the theoretical level should discuss this, but I don't have them at hand at the moment to confirm this. I also recall reading a popular science account once that attributed the off-shell property to the short lifetime (they created from the photon, and then annihilate shorly after) of the particles, which would allow for the off-shell energies by the energy-time uncertainty relation, but I don't think this could be made rigorous.